# Paying PayPal Billing Agreements without an account

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I'm using the PayPal-PHP-SDK to create billing agreements

Paying with a PayPal account is working, but I want the buyer to pay without an account (just a card)

There are 3 subscription plans:

[image]

If I select a subscription and click to my PayPal button, this calls the billing agreement creation to generate an approval link, and I redirect the page

```
        // console.log(prixTTC)
        $.ajax({
            url: "/vente/recurring_payment.php",
            method: "GET",
            data: "pack=" + pack + "&prixHT=" + prixHT + "&TVA=" + TVA + "&duree=" + duree + "&prixTTC=" + prixTTC + "&devise=EUR" + "&namePack=" + namePack + "&typePaiement=" + typeAbonnement ,

            dataType: "html",
            success: function(url){

                if( url ){
                    // console.log(url)
                    window.location.href = url
                }

            },
            error: function(){
                // TODO : Gestion de l'erreur
            }
        });
```

But I don't have the choice to pay with a card.

My question is :

How can I generate a button and pay this billing agreement directly with a card, without using a PayPal account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How generate button and pay billing agreement with credit card and without account paypal ?

You cannot. PayPal billing agreements require the payer to have or create a PayPal account during the billing agreement creation process.

It is not possible to create a PayPal billing agreement without a PayPal account.

Comment: Oh well.. Maybe i shouldn't use PayPal-PHP-SDK for that ? Or it's not possible

Comment: This applies to all PayPal billing agreements; the SDK or API used for the implementation will not matter.